# (KivyMD) How to call a function when using 2 kv files/strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have a kivymd app that has a screen with a button on it. When you click this button an MDCard will appear on the screen. When you click on this new MDCard it will call a function that will print a message on the terminal. However, I am having trouble getting this MDCard to call the function. I am getting the error:

```
 AttributeError: 'MDCard' object has no attribute 'option'
```

The MDCard is in a separate kv string from the main kv string. Essentially I have two kv strings. When you press the button, the second kv string will be added as a widget to the first kv string.

I figured it is because the second kv string doesn't have a class as a root but I don't know how to do this. How can I get the MDCard to call the function??

**MAIN.PY**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from button_screen import button_screen

MainNav = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: 'Go to Button Screen'
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "go_to_button_screen"

Screen:
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: "words_nav_item"
            button_screen:
                name: "go_to_button_screen"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class main_test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        return Builder.load_string(MainNav)


main_test().run()
```

**BUTTON SCREEN .PY FILE**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

button_screen_kv = '''
<button_screen>:
    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height
        spacing: 40
        md_bg_color: [0,0,.1,.1]
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 40

        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Button:
                text: "Click to add card"
                on_release:
                    root.add_card("card 1")
        
        MDGridLayout:
            id: add_card_here_id
            cols: 1

'''

md_card_kv = '''
MDCard:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "360dp", "120dp"
    ripple_behavior: True
    on_release:
        root.option("MDCard was clicked")
    MDLabel:
        id: LabelTextID
        text: "this is an MDCard"
        halign: 'center'
'''


class button_screen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Builder.load_string(button_screen_kv)
        self.md_card_widget = Builder.load_string(md_card_kv)

    def option(self, string):
        print(f"{string}")

    def add_card(self, *args):

        self.ids.add_card_here_id.add_widget(self.md_card_widget)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I came up with the following that works however, I am still new to programming so I don't know if this is a stable solution. Please advise me there**

**The Solution:**

- I added another class `class user_card(MDGridLayout)` in the `buttonscreen.py` and placed the kv string there.
- I set that class as the root widget in the kv string
- in the **init** method I placed a function that will return the kv string `return self.user_card_string`
- then I added that class as a parameter in the add_widget and passed the `col` as an argument: `self.ids.add_card_here_id.add_widget(user_card(cols=1))`

Everything works but I have never used two classes before. So I am unsure if this will present a future problem.

**button_screen.py:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

button_screen_kv = '''
<button_screen>:
    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height
        spacing: 40
        md_bg_color: [0,0,.1,.1]
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 40

        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Button:
                text: "Click to add card"
                on_release:
                    root.add_card("card 1")
        
        MDGridLayout:
            id: add_card_here_id
            cols: 1

'''

md_card_kv = '''
<user_card>:
    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 1
        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "360dp", "120dp"
            ripple_behavior: True
            on_release:
                root.option()
            MDLabel:
                id: LabelTextID
                text: "this is an MDCard"
                halign: 'center'
'''


class user_card(MDGridLayout):
    user_card_string = Builder.load_string(md_card_kv)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.load_card()

    def option(self, *args):
        print("MDCard was clicked")

    def load_card(self):
        return self.user_card_string


class button_screen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Builder.load_string(button_screen_kv)

    def add_card(self, *args):
        self.ids.add_card_here_id.add_widget(user_card(cols=1))
```